# Python: Handle Missing Files from a Sequence

Tags: python, file, exception, sequence, continue

I have a program that's basically as follows:

```
for l in range(0,100):  
 file = open("C:/Twitter/json/user_" + str(l) + ".json", "r")
 #do some stuff
 file.close()
```

I am trying to figure out a way to handle the exception that will be thrown if say file 20 is missing, and tell it to `continue`. I attempted to use the `continue` with a `try` statement however, it kept complaining that I wasn't putting it in the loop properly. Any advice would be appreciated.

Basically I tried:

```
try:
 for:
except:
 continue
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like :

```
import json
for l in xrange(100):
    try:
        with open('C:/Twitter/json/user_%d.json' % l, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            #do stuff with obj
    except IOError:
        pass
```

**edit** fixed the code.

Comment: Check the modified version, even more "pythonic" :), although the os.path.exists part below is also very valid, mine handles random errors though, like if the file exists but can't be read.

Comment: The problem with using os.path.exists is that the file may be deleted by another process between checking that it is there and opening it.

Comment: Yeah agreed, thats why it's probably safer to go with the try/except.

Answer (score 4):

you could check file existence and then open it:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists(file_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this though since it is a smaller amount of files, but both solutions worked for me.